# IP_PHONE_POWER_ADAPTER IN CISCO PACKET TRACER FOR MAC

Tags: cisco, packet-tracer, mac, powerconnect, cisco-7900-ip-phones

I'm using Cisco Packet Tracer v8.0.0 for Mac, and I'm having trouble connecting the ip_phone_power_adapter module of the "7960 ip phone" device. According to several tutorials, you just drag the module to the device and that's it, but it doesn't work for me. Can you help me, please.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any problem with attaching this but pay attention to "detail" as you need to lineup the plug to the inlet on the phone.

[image]